# How to assign roles on raw reaction?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to build a bot that assigns roles based on reactions. What am I doing wrong?

**CODE:**

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reacion_add(payload, user):
    message_id = payload.message_id

    if message_id == 750076609519943811:
        guild_id = payload.guild_id
        guild = discord.utils.find(lambda g : g.id == guild_id, client.guilds)

        if payload.emoji.name == 'Tigre':
            role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='+$100.000')
            await user.add_roles(role)
```

**EDIT:**

The bot starts just fine and it just not responding to this raw reaction

**EDIT 2**

Still nothing :(

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.message_id == 750087466765123647:

        bbc_emoji = '<:bbc:639345897922101248>'

        if payload.emoji.name == bbc_emoji:
            print ('working')
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code?

Comment: Nothing on the comment, just don't work idk why

Comment: Can you try it with `on_reaction_add`?

Answer (score 1):

You spelt the event name wrongly, it's `on_raw_reaction_add`. The event takes only one single parameter, namely `payload`. The second argument should not be there. If you want to get who added the reaction you can use `payload.member`. The emoji name will be `<:name:id>` not `"Tigre"`.

Answer (score 1):

The error lies in `if payload.emoji.name == bbc_emoji:`. If you cut the variable from the if-statement your code is

```py
if payload.emoji.name == '<:bbc:639345897922101248>':
```

However, the payload argument returns `emoji.name` and `emoji.id` seperately. You can check by running `print(payload)`.

Therefore, your code should be:

```py
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print(payload)
    if payload.message_id == 750087466765123647:
        if payload.emoji.id == 639345897922101248:
            print ('working')
```